# How to subscribe to actions from react-router

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, react-router, react-router-redux

I have the `React.JS` / `redux` / `react-router` / `react-router-redux` app. I have nested menu to navigate through the site. After user clicked on menu element - `react-router` fires action `@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE` (which leads to URL changes) and I manually fire action that leads to AJAX request and changes on the page (AJAX requests made with fetch() and chain of Promises).

Now I have one problem - after the user clicked 'back' in his browser or manually changed URL, URL updated but data on the page not. Router action fired and my custom action not...

I can easely switch my reducers from my custom action to `@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE`, but in this case I can not make AJAX requests -
 we can not dispatch new actions from reducers...

In other languages, I would subscribe to `@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE` and fire my custom action after router action fired, not after the button has been clicked. How to do this in React? How to subscribe to actions that fired by another components/middleware?

Comment: use withRouter to pass route properties to your component and from there determine whether you need to refetch data or not. the other option is to place a middleware in your store to listen for those route actions, but that is an obscure method. the component approach is cleaner and more and more transparent

Comment: Are you using the `history` library in `<Router history={history} />` ?

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon New iteration :) Now my navigation menu contains only links to different pages. My component has access to the router: `MyCompConnected = withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComp))`. My route: `path: 'stats/(:dataID)'`. My component checks URL params and invokes a callback (from `mapDispatchToProps`) to make AJAX request. First AJAX call performed well. But after that nothing happened - actions of `react-router` do not change props of my view component and it is not re-rendered. Any ideas why `withRouter` do not pass new `dataID` to the component?

Comment: where are you making the calls? usually when redial is not used people chooses to use componentWillMount to make the calls. are you sure your component is not rerendering when the route changes? i think it is, but your api calls are missplaced. i will recommend, if you are not using it yet, to use redial https://github.com/markdalgleish/redial